# The series $t + t^1 + t^2 + t^3 + \cdots + t^{n-1} + t^n$ in minimal computational steps

Tags: algorithms

What is the most efficient, in terms of computational steps, way to compute the mathematical series $t + t^1 + t^2 + t^3 + \cdots + t^{n-1} + t^n$ (when $n$ is a very large number, in the order of $10^{10}$ or so)? What I came up with was to factor the series into $4t(t + 1)(t^2 + 1)(t^4 + 1)(t^8 + 1)$, and to do so for the base-2 factors, $n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor} -  2^{\lfloor \log_2(n -2^{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor})\rfloor} - \cdots = 0$. That lets the series be calculated in $\log_2(n)$ steps.

Comment: Looks like a geometric series, for which there’s a formula

Comment: thank you. I felt like there was a better solution than I'd come up with. b + bt + bt^2 + bt^3 + bt^4 = b(1-t^5)/(1-t)

Comment: In general, when $|t|\ne 1$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n t^k = \frac{t(1-t^{n+1})}{1-t}. $$

Comment: To compute $t^n$ quickly for large $n$, consider exponentiation by squaring.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=1}^n t^k
=t\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t^k
=t\dfrac{t^n-1}{t-1}
$,
so this reduces to computing
$t^n$ as efficiently as possible.

This can generally be done
in about $\log_2(n)$
steps, though the minimum is,
in general, unknown.

Knuth has a detailed discussion
of this problem in one of his volumes.